# Can't restart kestrel

Tags: asp.net-core, supervisord, kestrel-http-server

I am using supervisor to run the kestrel process on Ubuntu 14.04.

Here is my supervisor config:

```
[program:website]
command=/usr/bin/dotnet /var/www/publish/Website.dll 
directory=/var/www/publish/
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stderr_logfile=/var/www/website.err.log
stdout_logfile=/var/www/website.out.log
environment=ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production
user=www-data
stopasgroup=true
stopsignal=INT
```

I have tried `sudo service restart supervisor` and `supervisorctl restart website`.

They both say they are stopping and starting process but my uploaded changes are not detected, it seems kestrel carries on running unaffected.

The only way I have of getting my changes to reflect is to restart the entire server which is inconvenient.

What is a better way for me to restart kestrel?

Comment: `Kill` Kestrel?

Comment: no process called kestrel. I kill dotnet but it doesn't work, still need server restart